# How do i add together values from all objects of a class in java?

Tags: java, object, foreach, accumulate

I am trying to retrieve certain values from multiple objects under the same class. I have used a for each loop to iterate through each object, and would like to create an aggregated total, representing the rating and the cost of the item from the objects.

The For Each loop in my parent class:

```
for (Song songObj : Song.returnSongs()) {
    totalSongCost += Double.parseDouble(songObj.getPrice());
    totalSongRating += Integer.parseInt(songObj.getRating());
}
```

The Child class ArrayList meant to store objects:

```
private int rating;
private String title;
private double price;
private boolean favorite;
private static int counter = 0;
private static ArrayList songArray = new ArrayList();

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Song
 */
public Song()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    rating = 0;
    title = "";
    price = 0.0;
    counter++;
    songArray.add(this);
}
public static ArrayList returnSongs() {
    return songArray;
}
```

When I compile the code I get an error message saying that an object cannot be converted to song. Is there a way to fix this, or an easier way to accomplish the same task?

Comment: You should probably have another class like "Album" that has the arrayList of Songs, because your current implementation won't work. You can't add the object that contains the list (i.e. Song) to the list (which is in Song).

Comment: @BenjaminLowry The object doesn't contain the list, because it's `static` and therefore not owned by any object.

Comment: @ajb Ah yes, my bad, didn't see that it was static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've ever read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), you will know that `ArrayList` is actually a *generic* class. That means you can give `ArrayList` a type.

The type of stuff that an array list can store depends on what type you gave it. But if you don't give it any type, it stores `Object`s! Here,

```
for (Song songObj : Song.returnSongs()) {
```

you want to get `Song` objects from an array list of `Object` objects, which makes no sense to the compiler. As a result, the error appears.

The solution to this problem is of course, give the array list a type so that it knows what type it should store.

Change this

```
private static ArrayList songArray = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
private static ArrayList<Song> songArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

and change this:

```
public static ArrayList returnSongs() {
```

to this:

```
public static ArrayList<Song> returnSongs() {
```

Comment: For some reason when i do this i only can access the most recent object and not all objects of the class, why is that?

Comment: Please make sure that `songArray` is declared `static`. @user6828298

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is a generic class. This means you can specify what class type it is meant to work with. if you change this:

```
private static ArrayList songArray = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
private static ArrayList<Song> songArray = new ArrayList<Song>();
```

Then the ArrayList class will understand that you're working with instances of Song.

**Edit:** as Jim Garrison pointed out, your `returnSongs()` method should also be changed to specify the class type in the same way.

```
public static ArrayList<Song> returnSongs() { ...
```

Comment: Don't forget to also change `public static ArrayList returnSongs() ` to `public static ArrayList<Song> returnSongs() ` and the generic type at the point where `returnSongs()` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unusual to have the `Song` class be responsible for keeping track of all of the songs within the application. That seems outside of the responsibility of that class, and perhaps better suited to be handled within a different class, either within your parent class or a new type specially defined.

Additionally, be careful when using types like [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). As your compiler will warn you, these require type parameters in angle brackets (i.e. `List<Type>`). You should make it a habit of addressing all compiler warnings, and of always specifying type parameters for *generic* types like `List`. In cases where you don't define your types correctly, things start to default to `Object`, which leads to the issue you faced here.

Below is an example of what this could look like, restructured to keep the `Song` class solely for attributes of the song itself:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parent {
    private static List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    private static double totalSongCost = 0.0;
    private static int totalSongRating = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        populateSongs();

        for (Song song : songs) {
            totalSongCost += songObj.getPrice();
            totalSongRating += songObj.getRating();
        }
    }

    private void populateSongs() {
        songs.add(new Song(5, "Hey Jude", 12.5));
        songs.add(new Song(4, "Angie", 11.5));
        songs.add(new Song(0, "Other", 10.5));
    }
}
```

Your song class would simply be this:

```
public class Song {
    private int rating = 0;
    private String title = "";
    private double price = 0.0;

    public Song(int rating, String title, double price) {
        this.rating = rating;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // Compressed for brevity
    public int getRating() { return rating; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public double getPrice() { return price; }
}
```